# I want to get properties value of dxf file after uploading on php based site

Tags: php, autocad

I am creating a php website where user will upload a dxf file(Autocad 2D) and we want to get all properties values which defined into the file like Size, part count, Materiel volume, machine space etc. So we can use that value to calculate the price and show to the user how much cost will it take to build.

Comment: Plz check how to ask a question in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

DXF is a text file. To extract information from it, you need to parse it according to the [documentation](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the pleasant information provided.  I have read this documentation carefully and also I have opened the DXF file in texteditor I understood many things but still not success to get all values and their name so can you provide me an example to get value in inches like this  [Screen Short](http://websitedesigningcompaniesinindia.com/calculation_example_image.jpg) and yes this screen short is in 3D but I need for 2D only for DXF file. You can provide me the example of your own file or you can download [example](http://websitedesigningcompaniesinindia.com/example.dxf) file.

Comment: Hi Maxence, Thanks for your such a great response. We have get the solution for my previous problem. But now facing another issue on the same file. We want to calculate total number of closed curves. Is there any idea in your mind or any formula you can help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Post the solution here friend

Answer (score 0):

According to Maxence answer you need to read the [DXF Specs](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf).
Basically a DXF file structure is something like this

```
$VARIABLE
values
...
$VARIABLE2
values2
...
```

You can see the file structure by opening with a simple text editor (like notepad, notepad++).

An example partial of a beginning of DXF file structure is

```html
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1009
  9
$INSBASE
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  9
$EXTMIN
 10
18.11598045401162
 20
8.4674829624706263
 30
0.0
  9
$EXTMAX
 10
26.228964858016312
 20
14.903999246397481
 30
0.0
  9
$LIMMIN
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
  9
$LIMMAX
 10
12.0
 20
9.0
  9
$ORTHOMODE
 70
     0
  9
```

From this part of code

```html
    $ACADVER
      1
    AC1009
      9
```

You can know the AutoCAD **version** which the file has been saved, from the DXF Specs PDF you can read that AC1009 code corresponds to **R11 and R12 AutoCAD version**.

```
AC1009 = R11 and R12;
```